# Unsigned Char Values in String

Tags: c++, string, char, unsigned

`char` takes values in the range of -128 to 127. By simply putting `unsigned` before `char` the range changes to 0-255.
How to achieve the same effect in a `string`? So that all `char`s in that string take values from 0-255?

Comment: Simply cast it (at character element level)!

Comment: @g-makulik can you be more specific by what you mean with 'casting the string'? Can't find anything useful on google about that.

Comment: @user2653125 g-makulik was not speaking about casting a string, but just a single character. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `char` takes values in the range of -128 to 127.

No.

`char` is implementation-defined, it could be either `signed char` or `unsigned char` depending on what your compiler chose to use. And `char` doesn't necessarily means `byte` BTW... (there are some platforms where a `char` is 16 bits for example)

If you want to ensure that a `char` is indeed an `unsigned char` then just cast it: `static_cast<unsigned char>(some_char_value)`

Comment: thanks, but where should i put this line of code? and does it affect STRINGS, because there is where i am interested in..

Comment: @user2653125 Strings are just a series of characters, it's really not that hard once you stop and think about it for a few seconds. As to where you should put this line of code, you didn't show any of your own code so I can't tell. The idea is: wherever you use a `char` *and* want to ensure the value is unsigned, then you should use it.

Comment: here for example: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x="Hello";
    x[3]=150;
    cout<<int(x[3]);
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: @user2653125 `cout << (int)static_cast<unsigned char>(x[3]);`

Comment: i am sorry, i confused you.. the cout was just for meaning that without static_cast it shows negative value. But i dont want to change it before cout, i want to change it in the very beginning. The problem is because i want to write a program that treats strings as numbers, and i want to perform some math operations on each char of the string. So when i get the string by cin, all its characters are by default with value 0-255. Please help?

Comment: @user2653125 Oh my. Not to seem rude or anything, but *you* obviously are confused. Bit patterns can't be changed, the only thing that can vary is the way we interpret them. eg. `0xFF` can be either 255 or -1 depending on what *you* expect. But you gotta remember that this interpretation only happens when you *read* the value. **Every time** you use a `char`, if you want to make sure it is unsigned then you must cast it. *Everywhere*. There is no other way around.

Comment: sorry but i not a pro in c++. ok, now i understand that we are actually working with bit patterns, that are later interpreted as numbers when we cout them as int(x[i]). But how can i make it that BY DEFAULT it interprets the chars in the range of 0-255, by just writing a single line maybe? Since i don't want to type cast any single time, that would slow down the program..

Comment: i gues i got the answer after your last edit. i feel so sad, but thank you. One last thing, does this cast slow my algorithm?

Comment: @user2653125 No, such a cast doesn't slow down your program, again it's just a way to interpret the raw data, but the data itself never changes. As to making it the default, I would **strongly** advise against it: your code might be re-used in contexts where the default is not the same, and this would create bugs. Just stick to the standard: you can't know whether `char` is signed or not, so if you want reliability you have to cast it before using it.

Comment: look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/ just found it.
**The _basic_string_ is the generalization of class _string_ for any character type (see string for a description).** i think this is what i was looking for.. maybe by using this i can create a string of unsigned chars, isn't it?

Comment: Type `char` has the same size and representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but they're still three distinct types.